# HTML/PHP/JS Select multiple file and upload via FTP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ftp

Hy, I need to upload a series of files to a server (in specific a set of images). 
I need a single file input to select multiple files (also in IE), I have no permission to write directly with PHP on the server (permission are 775 but FTP and apache users are into 2 different groups) so I need to use an FTP connection (I'm already able to do this with a single file).
Can someone advice me if there is someway to do this?
Thanks in advance

Michele

Edit: I'm trying to use uploadify as Nick suggested.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#file_upload').uploadify({
            'uploader'  : 'JS/uploadify.swf',
            'script'    : 'upload.php',
            'cancelImg' : 'JS/cancel.png',
            'folder'    : 'TEST/UPLOADS',
            'auto'      : true,
            'multiple'  : true,
            'removeCompleted' : false,
            'queueSizeLimit' : 3,
            'queueID' : 'queue',
            'simUploadLimit' : 1
         );
    });
</script>
```

I tried to put ftp connection and ftp_put into upload.php it is right??
If I try to add the 'scriptData' parameter it cannot be accessible by $_POST[] as suggested by documentation, why?

here my test link: [test](http://www.wpr.it/TEST)

The test shows that files get uploaded but no files in the server's folder.

here is my upload.php code:

```
if (!empty($_FILES)) {
    $tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];                          // 1

    //$targetPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $_REQUEST['folder'] . '/';  // 2
    //$targetFile =  str_replace('//','/',$targetPath) . $_FILES['Filedata']['name']; // 3


    $ftp_server = "***";  //address of ftp server.
    $ftp_user_name = "***"; // Username
    $ftp_user_pass = "***";   // Password
    $conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);
    ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass); 
    ftp_pasv ( $conn_id, true );

    if( ftp_fput($conn_id, 'TEST/' . $_FILES['Filedata']['name'], $tempFile, FTP_BINARY)){                       // 4
        echo true;
    }else{
        echo false;
    }

    ftp_close($conn_id);
} else {
    echo false;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To allow the upload of multiple files I usually use [uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/)
It's documentation is fairly good, and it's pretty simple to use.

You need to use something like this in order to keep the connection open and send the files without reloading the page.

EDIT:

Your code should be something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('#custom_file_upload').uploadify({
        'uploader'       : 'JS/uploadify.swf',
        'script'         : 'JS/uploadify.php',
        'cancelImage'      : 'JS/uploadify-cancel.png',
        'multi'          : true,
        'auto'           : true,
        'fileTypeExts'        : '*.jpg',
        'fileTypeDesc'       : 'Image Files (.JPG)',
        'queueID'        : 'custom-queue',
        'queueSizeLimit' : 3,
        'simUploadLimit' : 3,
        'sizeLimit'   : 10240000,
        'removeCompleted': false,
        'onDialogClose'   : function(queue) {
            $('#status-message').text(queue.filesQueued + ' files have been added to the queue.');
        },
        'onQueueComplete'  : function(stats) {
            $('#status-message').text(stats.successful_uploads + ' files uploaded, ' + stats.upload_errors + ' errors.');
        }
    });             
});
</script>
```

`swf` changed to `uploader` and `uploader` changed to `script`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'm trying to use it but I'm confused on versions used in demos and documentation :S Also on trying passing scriptData parameters... do you have a working example? Or I may post my code...

Comment: if I change as you suggest the button won't work... you can see my test page here: [link](http://wpr.it/ADMIN/back_saver.php)

Comment: [test](http://www.wpr.it/TEST) it shows that it reach a complete upload but there is no files in the folder

Comment: You seem to have a full path to the cancelImage, script and uploader. This only needs to be a URL (and can be relative). Yours is currently `/app02/httpd/html/10001_1001_www.wpr.it_01/html/ADMIN/...` change it to `/ADMIN/...` and it looks like it's working for me (although I can't check the images are actually uploading properly, they are being passed to the script correctly).